# Accessing a column from a JSON table using R

Tags: r, json

I have read a JSON data file named `df` using fromJSON(). It has a table:

```
$table$info 
id  OrderNum Tags.store
124 1        Great
125 2        Book
126 5        Nice
125 <NA>     Cool
128 1        <NA>
```

I tried `df$$table$info$Tags.store` but nothing is returned. `id` and `OrderNum` works well. Are there any turnabouts?

Comment: can you show the `str(df)` or the `dput(df)`

Comment: thanks i got it. i realised that i can access it by $table$info$Tags$store

Answer (score 0):

To get the data.frame:

```r
df$table$info$Tags.store
```

or to get the column:

```r
df$table$info$Tags.store
```

---

If that doesn't work, try getting the data.frame first:

```r
newdf <- df$table$info
```

and then explore it like so:

```
names(newdf)
```